# How to run iostream system command in the same thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, shell, system, std

I'm trying to execute a command using std::system from Unreal Engine C++

```
FString command = FString("start /B cmd /k python \"D:/app.py\"");
std::string comm(TCHAR_TO_UTF8(*command));
std::system(comm.c_str());
```

The command itself is working as expected, however, I need it to execute on the current thread, or alternatively check if it's finished before continuing because the next operations depend on the completion of this command

Is there a way to do it? or maybe I should use another command?

Thanks, Eden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [std::system](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) function will not return until the command you execute have finished running.

Also on Windows (which you seem to be running) then [`system`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=vs-2019) will invoke the command interpreter (`cmd`) for execution of the command, which means the command you want to execute must be in the command interpreters `PATH` (or be an internal command of the command interpreter).

If `python` is in the `PATH`, then you could run the `python` command directly, without using `start` or `cmd` (especially since then you would have *two* instances of `cmd` running), and the `system` function would block and not return until the `python` command finished running:

```
FString command = FString("python \"D:/VRoscopy_repo/VRoscopy/conversion/invesalius3-master/app.py\" --no-gui -i \"D:\VRoscopy_repo\DICOM\Human\MedDream\Body\" -t 200,3033 -e \"D:\VRoscopy_repo\DICOM\Human\MedDream\Body/VRoscopy27777BED4B650CE6AFE884B365C56BCC.stl\"");
```